# How can I download an mp4 file using the 'download' property of HTML's a link?

Tags: html

I want to be able to download the "video.mp4" file with the code below.

`<a href="video.mp4" download>download</a>`

However, it is not downloaded and played.

How can I make it downloaded without being played?

Comment: since you are not adding the name of the download content. you are not getting the resource content in the format you want. Try the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<resource_link>" download="video.mp4" target="_blank">download</a>
```

Comment: I'm sorry.
I tried it, but it still plays without being downloaded.

Comment: could you put screenshot of what getting downloaded.

Comment: please make sure you are adding the extension along with the filename for download attribute.